# When debugging, GoLand can not evaluate a function on M1

Tags: go, arm64, apple-m1, goland

When debugging, use the `Evaluate expression` and try to evaluate a function. The result is shown as: "backend does not support function calls". Why?

MacBook Pro M1
GoLand 2021.1.3
Go 1.16.5 arm64

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See this: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2277

Per the comments: "[...] function call injection is not supported on arm64 because the Go runtime doesn't have an implementation for it."

Answer (score 4):

As of go 1.18.2, debug func is also supported on ARM64/Apple M1 (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52699). Seems like Goland still needs to update in order to use this. But there is hope :)